# SSCollectionViewItem selected state?

Tags: iphone, ios, sstoolkit

I am using SSToolkit and SSCollectionView.  When I click a SSCollectionViewItem, I would like to darken the item so the user knows it has been pressed.

The documentation (http://sstoolk.it/documentation/Classes/SSCollectionViewItem.html) shows a setSelected and setHighlighted method, but I am not sure how then to change the appearance of my item.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

*The answer is in the documentation:*

> Discussion
>
> Highlights or unhighlights the item,
>   animating the transition between
>   regular and highlighted state if
>   animated is YES. Highlighting affects
>   the appearance of the items's labels,
>   image, and background.
>
> **Note that for highlighting to work properly, you must fetch the item's
>   label (or labels) using the textLabel
>   (and detailTextLabel) properties and
>   set the label's highlightedTextColor
>   property; for images, get the items's
>   image using the imageView property and
>   set the UIImageView object's
>   highlightedImage property.**
>
> A custom table item may override this
>   method to make any transitory
>   appearance changes.

[SSCollectionViewItem](http://sstoolk.it/documentation/Classes/SSCollectionViewItem.html#setSelected%3aanimated%3a)